# Would this 3-phase sequence detector circuit work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, power-electronics, ltspice, design

I was searching for a circuit that would detect 3 phase sequence and give dry contact output if the sequence is correct.

I have found the schematic below, from a Daikin compressor manual. I wonder if this will work if I assemble it?

[image: Schematic of 3ph sequence control:]

[image: Bill of metarial]

[image: Described rated voltage per input T1-T2]

As you can see all part of the elements value table given above. I have already checked this circuit at LTspice simulator and it seems it’s ok but im not sure yet. Because, I cannot see any voltage between relay coil on simulator also at 1C which sharing same nodes with relay coil. I can only see 24 V at when I attached probes between 1C (positive side) and 1ZD (anode side). This situation made me confused. What you are thinking, is that circuit can work at 400 V 50 Hz 3 phase lines? Otherwise which modifications needed?

Note: 1SA described at table as "Rheostat" . But im thinking of its a "SA" series TVS diode which manufactered by Littelfuse. If im wrong , correct me please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's redraw the circuit diagram so it'll be more legible. Then we can simulate it and see what it does :)

CircuitLab is built into this website in both the question editor and in the answer editor - to use it, click the schematic icon:

[image]

And thus the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKqPMp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The relay has a 0.1mH (guessed), 2.8kΩ (per the datasheet), 24V coil.

And the good news is:

### It works! :)

When SW2 is as shown, the phase order is R-S-T, and the relay and the lamp turns on:

[image]
[image]

When SW2 is flipped, and the phase order is reversed to S-R-T, the relay stays off:

[image]
[image]